# Win32com: Close a specific Excel file if it's opened

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I just want to check if a specfic Excel file is open. If it is, I want to close **only** that file.

In the below code, using:

```
xl.Workbooks.Close()
```

closes all open Excel files.

Using:

```
xl.Workbooks.Close(FileName=xlPath)
```

leads to

```
TypeError: Close() got an unexpected keyword argument 'FileName'.
```

Complete code:

```
import win32com.client as w3c

xl=w3c.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")

my_workbook = "test.xlsx"
xlPath='C:/Desktop/test.xlsx'

if xl.Workbooks.Count > 0:
    if any(i.Name == my_workbook for i in xl.Workbooks):
        xl.Workbooks.Close(FileName=xlPath)

xl.Workbooks.Close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the Excel object library docs, [**`Workbook.Close`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.close) is a method of the `Workbook` object. Therefore, use the workbook object in your iteration which is `i` (renamed below to `wb` for clarity). Also, your `any()` expression will not capture i-th workbook in order to close. So run name check inside for-loop.

```py
...
if xl.Workbooks.Count > 0: 
    for wb in xl.Workbooks:
        if wb.Name == my_workbook: 
            wb.Close()
```